# One MsgBox To show all passes and fails

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I am trying to make one message box to include passes and fails of samples.

[image: Data]

All Ranges above 0.24 are a fail and below are a pass, and that to show in one box the passes and fails with correspondent sample #

The code below, show the boxes one by one and even incorrectly, some are blank and some not correct.

May you help me with this please. Thanks

```
Sub MsgB()
Dim x As Long
For x = 2 To 8
    If Sheet2.Range("B" & x).Value < 0.24 Then
       y = Sheet2.Range("A" & x).Value
      MsgBox "Pass: " & y
   Else
     MsgBox "Fail: " & y
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could accumulate the results in two string variables as shown below, and display the results after the loop has completed. Also, `y` is set only if the value is smaller than `0.24`. You need to set `y` before the `If`.

```
Sub MsgB()
Dim x As Long
Dim pass as String
pass = ""
Dim fail as String
fail = ""
For x = 2 To 8
    y = Sheet2.Range("A" & x).Value
    If Sheet2.Range("B" & x).Value < 0.24 Then
        pass = pass & ", " & y
    Else
        fail = fail & ", " & y
    End If
Next
' Print pass and fail, removing the leading ", ".
pass = Right(pass, Len(pass) - 2)
fail = Right(fail, Len(fail) - 2)
MsgBox "Pass: " & pass & vbCrLf & "Fail: " & fail
```

End Sub

Comment: Can I accumulate passes and fails in one text box? Also to add "," between each one

Comment: Yes, I will update my answer.

Comment: I did not test the update!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can combine all passes and fails within one message box by concatenating strings and providing output only once:

```
Sub MsgB()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim passes As String, fails As String

    With Sheet2

        For x = 2 To 8
            If .Range("B" & x).Value < 0.24 Then
                passes = passes & ", " & .Range("A" & x)
            Else
                fails = fails & ", " & .Range("A" & x)
            End If
        Next x

    End With    

    MsgBox "Pass: " & Mid(passes, 3) & vbLf & "Fail: " & Mid(fails, 3)

End Sub
```