# How to show all fails if there is any, if not then show no fail box

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I want to show MsgBox of fails with correspondent samples. If non show another MsgBox with no fail.

I feel I am almost there but have something messing.

If I put the MsgBox within the loop the MsgBox appears more than once, if I put it out it shows both MsgBox of "fails" if any and "There are no Fails"

How can I show only one of them with the (If-statement), and of course show once. Either box showing all fails or box showing there are none.

The code I ran:

```
Sub Box()
Dim x As Long
Dim fails As String
'Dim passes As String

With Sheet2
    For x = 2 To 8
        If .Range("E" & x).Value > 0.24 Then
        fails = fails & ", " & .Range("A" & x)
        MsgBox "Failed Strut: " & fails
        ElseIf .Range("E" & x).Value < 0.24 Then
        passes = "There are no fails"
        MsgBox passes
        End If
    Next x
End With

'Other attempts
'MsgBox passes
'fails = Right(fails, Len(fails) - 2)
'MsgBox "Failed Strut: " & fails

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One MsgBox To show all passes and fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525644/one-msgbox-to-show-all-passes-and-fails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to feed the `fails`variable with the ranges you want to show and then check if your variable is empty or not. Also, there is no need to feed a `passes`variable because it will always be the same:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Box()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim fails As String
    'Dim passes As String

    With Sheet2
        For x = 2 To 8
            If .Range("E" & x).Value > 0.24 Then
                If fails = vbNullString Then
                    fails = .Range("A" & x)
                Else
                    fails = fails & ", " & .Range("A" & x)
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    End With

    'Here you check wether you send one message or the other
    If Not fails = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Failed Strut: " & fails
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no fails"
    End If

    'Other attempts
    'MsgBox passes
    'fails = Right(fails, Len(fails) - 2)
    'MsgBox "Failed Strut: " & fails

End Sub
```

Finally, indenting correctly your code makes it more easy to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly. How will I remove the header "," without making an error out of if there are no fails. I used (fails = Right(fails, Len(fails) - 2)) but could show error if not any fails

Comment: @Moe if I understood you correctly, my edit should help.